# Joining a table with itself where there is a datestamp and with a secondary date variable?

Tags: sql

I have a table - it is like several table concatenated because [Col1] takes two different strings and [Value] takes numerical values relating to [Col1] string. There are 2 sets of columns for segments. Analysis for each segment and later combination of segments. datestamp is also available.

```
Col1   datestamp Value Col4  Col5  ColD
ret     1/10/14                     0
ret     1/11/14                     1
ret     1/11/14                     0
ent     1/10/14                     0
ent     1/11/14                     1
```

Finished table will look like this:

```
    Col1ret  Col2ent  datestamp Col4  Col5  ColD Value-ret Value-ent
    ret       ent     1/10/14                0
    ret       ent     1/11/14                1
    --
    --
```

What would be the SQL script to do this?

Comment: Its simple. Show your efforts.

Comment: suposed in first row, Col4 = 1 and fourth row, Col4=0, what the value at Col4 in finished table will be?

Comment: Col4 and Col5 are text and will not take numerical value. Likely they will be identical. Think about a concatenated table - I am trying to split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with Aggregated `CASE`. Something like this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/458ee/1)

**Query**

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'ret' THEN Col1  ELSE NULL END) as Col1ret,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'ent' THEN Col1  ELSE NULL END) as Col1ent,
    datestamp,Col4,ColD,Col5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'ret' THEN Value  ELSE NULL END) as valueret,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'ent' THEN Value  ELSE NULL END) as valueent
FROM tbl
GROUP BY datestamp,Col4,ColD,Col5;
```

**Output**

```
| Col1ret | Col1ent |                 datestamp |   Col4 | ColD |   Col5 | valueret | valueent |
|---------|---------|---------------------------|--------|------|--------|----------|----------|
|     ret |     ent | January, 10 2014 00:00:00 | (null) |    0 | (null) |   (null) |   (null) |
|     ret |  (null) | January, 11 2014 00:00:00 | (null) |    0 | (null) |   (null) |   (null) |
|     ret |     ent | January, 11 2014 00:00:00 | (null) |    1 | (null) |   (null) |   (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks @ughai - what is the purpose of MAX here? Also can you still do it without GROUP BY?

Comment: Since these fields are not present in `group by`, you need some aggregation to happen on these fields. I have used `MAX`